# heroku rails 3 code error in production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I've moved my app to heroku and went fine. It starts the application fine when I have no records in cars.

It starts the application fine when I have no records in cars

When I add a new car I get this error in heroku log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "t"
  SELECT  "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE ("uploads".car_id = 1 AND (file_avatar = 't')) LIMIT 1):
     23:         <% if logged_in? && current_user.id == 1 -%>
     24:           <%= link_to "Select Main Photo", setmain_car_path(@car),  :remote => true, :class => 'setmain' %>
     25:         <% end %>
     26:         <% if @car.profile_avatar.nil? %>
     27:         <div id="no_picture"><%= image_tag('na.jpeg') %></div>
     28:         <% else %>
     29:         <li style="list-style:none;">
   app/views/cars/show.html.erb:26:in `_app_views_cars_show_html_erb___1259288943457494717_26795060_2985470889244562248'
```

in development mode on my localhost I have no such error. Any help would be appreciated.

this is the view.html code that refers to this error

```
<div class="latest_box">
    <div class="latest_bg"></div>
    <div class="last_added">Last added</div>
    <div class="latest_image">
      <% @cars.each do |car| %>
      <div class="latest_item">
        <% if car.profile_avatar.nil? %>
        <%= image_tag('rails.png') %>
        <% else %>
        <%=link_to image_tag(car.profile_avatar.photo.url(:thumb)), car %>
        <% end %><br />
        <b><%= link_to car.carname.name, car %></b>
        <b><%= link_to car.carmodel.name, car %></b><br />
        <%= car.category %><br />
        <%= number_to_currency(car.price) %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**Car model**

```
has_many :carname
  has_many :carmodel
  has_one :profile_avatar, :class_name => "Upload", :foreign_key => "car_id", :conditions => ['file_avatar = ?', true]
  has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say (in a comment) that you're developing on top of MySQL. MySQL uses integer columns for booleans with 1 for true and 0 for false. PostgreSQL has a native boolean type that accepts various things for true and false, Rails uses `'t'` and `'f'` when working with PostgreSQL.

You have this:

```
:conditions => ['file_avatar = ?', true]
```

and that's causing your trouble. So, I'd guess that you created `file_avatar` as an integer column and everything worked fine in development because a Ruby `true` is converted to `1` by the MySQL adapter. Everything falls apart on Heroku because the PostgreSQL adapter converts `true` to `'t'` and PostgreSQL doesn't want to compare that to your integer `file_avatar` column.

Your best bet is to change `file_avatar` to a boolean column with a migration:

```
change_column :uploads, :file_avatar, :boolean
```

Then, once you have this immediate problem sorted out, change your development environment to PostgreSQL 8.3 (if you're deploying to a shared Heroku database) or PostgreSQL 9.0 (if you're deploying to a dedicated database). Developing and deploying on the same stack will save you from a lot of needless pain and suffering.

Comment: This.  I knew I'd run into the same issue when I used to be on mySQL, my explanation / suggestion were woefully incomplete.

Comment: @RSG: But you did spot and draw out the underlying problem ("You're using a different local database, aren't you?") and that's definitely an improvement over "WTF is going on?".

Comment: can I asky you here one more thing.. i have in cars controller a piece of code  @cars_see_special = Car.where(:special => "yes").limit(3)  that will bring to display 3 cars with special value "yes" (special offer cars). In heroku they don't show up, I think it has to do with the fact that herpku uses postgres. How can I change this code so I can get the neede result, I woudn'y like to get into database modifications. Thanks.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: `Car.where(:special => "yes").limit(3)` should work the same on both except, possibly, for case handling differences. Are the `:special` values `'yes'`, `'YES'`, `'Yes'`, or ...?

Comment: thanks, I allready changed the column value to boolean, works fine, but I now this thing came up: <% if @car.special.nil? %> is not good anymore, how can I change this code to look if special is true? <% if @car.special == 1 %> not giving the result I need.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: `<% if @car.special %>` should do it (assuming that you want `nil` to be the same as `false` of course).

Answer (score 2):

You're using a different local database, aren't you?  Your raw SQL is not playing nicely with postgres.  You need to substitute the postgres "true" for your 't'.

```
(file_avatar = 'true')
```

Comment: what you mean different database? I use mysql database.

Comment: Heroku uses Postgres.  There are a few annoying syntax differences between the two databases- any time you write raw SQL instead of using active record you run the risk of deploying incompatible code.  It'll save you some headaches to switch your dev environment to Postgres.

Comment: where should I change this? <% if car.profile_avatar = 'true' %>  ??

Comment: Oh hm.  I skimmed the code when I saw the error message. Can you post more details about the car model?  How are you handling your uploads on Heroku?

Comment: added it in the main question